# Cross server symlinks and Crontab

Tags: linux, cron, symlink

I've been tasked with trying to implement the following scenario.  What I'd like to know is whether this is feasible/doable?

There will 4+ servers. For ease I'll call them Server A, Server B, Server C, Server D

Server A is the command and control server. It will contain the scripts (PHP) that will get executed by Cron Tab jobs.  There will also be an application on Server A that will allow the user to select scripts to run and specify which server they will run on. So that app will create the Cron tab jobs on the specified server.

So far so good - using the SSH2 lib I can create the cron entries on the target servers.

I know that I can use symlinks in a Crontab entry.

Is it possible to create a symlink that points from Server B, Server C or Server D to Server A.

So basically I want Server A to issue/maintain the Cron tab on the other servers, to store all the scripts but the when the other server jobs run, they run the scripts stored on Server A.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symlink only tells the OS to substitute another path and try accessing the file again. The access still occurs only on the local file system.

You need to mount server A's file system on the other servers via some means such as [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), [NFS](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/), or [Samba](http://www.samba.org/).

Instead, why not just copy the script down to the target server before running it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - copying the script to the target server was my first proposal. At the moment this is a feasibility study. I'll investigate sshfs but my instinct is that the extra complexity of trying to keep all the scripts on one server will out weigh the benefits. Whilst this is initially only 4-5 servers, it may grow to 20+.